# ROS Window Gmapping Install

Tags: gmapping, ros-noetic, windows

Is there a way to install gmapping on ros windows?
It doesn't seem to be in the chocolatey package list.
I also tried to run catkin_make myself, but a ninja error occurred.

============================================================

```
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Could NOT find openslam_gmapping (missing: openslam_gmapping_DIR)
-- Could not find the required component 'openslam_gmapping'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at C:/opt/ros/noetic/x64/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "openslam_gmapping"
  with any of the following names:

    openslam_gmappingConfig.cmake
    openslam_gmapping-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "openslam_gmapping" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "openslam_gmapping_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "openslam_gmapping" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  slam_gmapping/gmapping/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

https://github.com/OpenSLAM-org/openslam_gmapping
https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping.git

This error occurred when I cloned the above source and ran catkin_make.
This worked fine on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

Looking at [the Wiki](https://wiki.ros.org/gmapping), the package is a ROS orphaned package. However, I found a [discussion on the Noetic release](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/issues/94) of this package. Please go through it.

Comment: Is a way to install orphaned package?

Comment: Please try installing from source!

Comment: I have updated the error list in the post

Comment: It is looking for `openslam_gmapping` as a dependency. Please install it and recompile.

Comment: I include openslam_gmapping and run catkin_make to install.
Isn't this the way it is?
I suspect openslam_gmapping does not build on Windows.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familier with Windows. What does `$ rospack find openslam_gmapping` says?

Comment: [rospack] Error: package 'openslam_gmapping' not found

Comment: As expected. You need to install it. Let's stop chatting in this section. Thanks for kind cooperation